# How to prevent an error when listing the length of a firebase child node in vue.js using an "Object.keys" function?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, vue.js

Imagine a Vue.js app where the data structure in firebase will develop into something like this:

```
item: {
  name: itemName,
  childOne: {
    subChildA: true,
    subChildB: true
  },
  childTwo: {
    subChildA: true,
    subChildB: true
  }
}
```

Now I have a component where I need to list the length of the child nodes (these child nodes will only be added later).
My first thought was to simply do this, but this strategy doesn't work:

```
<tbody>
  <tr v-for="item in items" >
     <td>
        {{item.childOne.length - item.childTwo.length}}
     </td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

So alternatively I got the length like this:

```
<tbody>
   <tr v-for="item in items" >
      <td>
         {{Object.keys(item.childOne).length - Object.keys(item.childTwo).length}}
      </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

As I said I need to render that component before the item's children are created... These child nodes are later conditionally created through a Google Cloud Function so I inevitably start with this simple structure:

```
item: {
  name: itemName,
}
```

...but at this stage I get an error message:

> TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
>       at Function.keys ()

I am thinking that if I use the first strategy, vue.js is smart enough to avoid this error **renders the component, and displays nothing if there are no children, but it can't get the lengths**.

The second strategy **works perfectly when I add the children but it can't deal with the initial absence of data and doesn't even render the view**.

Is there anyway to prevent this error using the second strategy when the child nodes are not there yet?

Comment: Why not just start with an empty `childOne`, ie `item: { name: itemName, childOne: {} }`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the double pipe operator to supply a default empty object for instances where `item.childOne` or `item.childTwo` are not defined.

Change this:

```
{{Object.keys(item.childOne).length - Object.keys(item.childTwo).length}}
```

To this:

```
{{Object.keys(item.childOne || {}).length - Object.keys(item.childTwo || {}).length}}
```

Small scale example:

```js
var test = {};
console.log(Object.keys(test.childOne || {}).length);
```

However, you should be mindful that Vue cannot detect property additions or deletions. As per the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats):

> Since Vue performs the getter/setter conversion process during instance initialization, a property must be present in the data object in order for Vue to convert it and make it reactive.

Depending on your exact use case, you may need to define `childOne` during initialization or convert it to an array so that you may take advantage of Vue's [observed array mutation methods](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Array-Change-Detection).

Comment: Yes. That's a great solution! :)